# What is the correct way to iterate over controller properties in a template?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

It's not entirely clear how to iterate over controller properties in a template.  I stumbled on a method:

```
{{#each-in this as |key value|}}
    {{key}}: {{value}}
{{/each-in}}
```

and that kind of works, but it's outputting some internal functions in addition to the properties:

```
q: shirt
search_page: 3
_qpDelegate: function (prop, value) { var qp = map[prop]; _this._qpChanged(prop, value, qp); return _this._activeQPChanged(map[prop], value); }
```

My controller looks like:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

    queryParams: [
        'q',
        'search_page'
    ],
    q: 'shirt',
    search_page: 3

});
```

Is there a way to iterate and exclude the functions?

Comment: What is your need for this? One simple solution could be to filter out functions with a custom helper. `{{#each-in this as |key value|}} {{#if (not-function value)}}
    {{key}}: {{value}}
{{/if}}
{{/each-in}}`

Comment: the query params API stores the keys/values in controllers properties.  right now I am just wanting to test various actions on the properties themselves by printing them all out without having to specify them.

Comment: have you try to use `{{debugger}}` inside your view for this purpose? and then you can inspect the property value inside the console

Comment: I have.  I'm just trying to keep my view clean as I am developing - printing the functions clutters it up.  More of a housekeeping thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it appears you only need to do this for debugging purposes, one possible solution would be to create a custom helper to filter out functions (or whatever else you want):

```
// helpers/debug-filter.js
export function debugFilter([value]) {
  return Ember.typeOf(value) !== 'function';
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(formatCurrency);
```

Your controller's template

```
{{#each-in this as |key value|}}
  {{#if (debug-filter value)}}
    {{key}}: {{value}}
  {{/if}}
{{/each-in}}
```